# OpenCV imread from Hadoop/HDFS

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop, image-processing, hdfs

I have successfully tested opencv in hadoop to read and analyze images from local filesystem in a mapreduce job.

But how to enable opencv to read images from HDFS instead of local filesystem?

Comment: basically, if you can't fopen() it, imread() is doomed.

Comment: @berak, any suggestions on work around?

Comment: not really, unfortunately. if you can get some byte[] buffer any other way, there's imdecode()

Comment: Hello @Joel, I am having problem in testing opencv with hadoop. As you said, you  have successfully tested it, Can you please help me. I am getting error, UnsatisfiedLinkError , native method not found. I have also posted question regarding this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270351/opencv-library-loaded-in-hadoop-but-not-working